# What is meant by "Process holding a resource"?

Tags: process, operating-system, deadlock

I mean even if a resource is shareable and if one process is holding it then whether another process can use the resource which first process is ***holding***?

Comment: In general, Holding means having possession of asset for use. The Holding nature will decide whether other process can use in which way. It all depends on the read/write/execute permissions. Some resources such as CPU can not be used simultaneously by more than one process

Comment: Thank you ...............................                                      .

Answer (score 1):

Yes but with specified operations or limited operations allowerd on it.

**Case 1:**
If process 1 is  holding that resource for w/r/x(write/read/execute) then second process can only use it for read and execute purpose so as other possessor try  to access that shared area.

**Case 2:**
If Process 1 holding that resource only of reading purpose, then other process can hold shared resource for w/r/x

Answer (score 0):

Example: Resource -> File

If A process  opens file. after that writes into this file. When A process is writing data into the file then B process is also writing data into same file.
 So, Both Process are writing in same file at a time . So data present in the file is corrupted. So, we can say that at a time Both Processes (A and B ) are  holding the resource(file). So we can use fcntl function to lock the file. In the thread we can use semaphore and mutex lock. So, The programmer's responsibility is to lock the resources(file).